# Java Spring boot Application after few request 502 bad gateway

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, jboss

I am having an issue with my java spring boot application,

**application function:**
it's a simple HTTP post-URI application, i.e., my application will do an HTTP post call to a URI, and get the information (JSON) and send back the information, and from my API the JSON body from the URI will be sent to services.

**problem:**
so for the first few request, there is no issue, I will be able to get the response without any error, after few hits like after 30+ requests I am having 502 BAD Gateway. I am using the tomcat default server given by spring boot. FYI the source uri is working fine. no issues with source uri.

the response time is 300ms-90ms

**solutions tried:**
changed from java.net.http to org.apache.http

i have read online there was a limitation in tomcat, so i have even deployed this application in jboss eap and javax.servlet.api, still the error continues.

i have closed the httpclient and CloseableHttpResponse still the error continues.

dependencies used:

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```